# QGIS2web not updating on 3.4.5

Tags: qgis-plugins, web-mapping, qgis2web

[image]

I am using QGIS 2.18. Upon making updates to my map, the update is not showing in the export to map web page. I have updated it several times and restarted QGIS but it is not replicating my label styling.

I updated my map to the first image using the size assistant function for the proportional circle. However, when I export to map using the QGIS2web plugin, it still gives me the old representation called capture 1. [image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXib8.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYL8o.png This is the result, it is still not updating in qgis2web.
[image: I have tried it again in QGIS 3.4.5 using the size assistant]

Comment: Please improve the question providing the information of how are you styling you labels. Also, take in account that QGIS 2 is not mantained any more.

Comment: does this means that any data that was overridden using the data driven overide button on size can not be updated in the web map?

Answer (score 2):

I think the specific styling features you are using are not supported in versions of qgis2web compatible with QGIS2. As Gabriel De Luca says, QGIS2 is no longer supported, and qgis2web no longer supports QGIS2 either. There have been many subsequent releases of qgis2web, compatible with QGIS3 only, with bugfixes and features which will not be present in the qgis2web version you are using.

Comment: I just tried it in QGIS 3.4.5 and got the same result.  The over ridden data is not reflecting in the wep map. So does this means that any data that was overridden using the data driven overide button on size can not be updated in the web map?

Comment: I used proportional circles for the two values in the map above. One has a value of 1-13 while the other has values from 25-93. So the proportional circles were not equal as the ones having 13 were far bigger than 30 within the 25-93 range. So I decided to costomize and define the size of the circles using the data defined override which allows you specify the sizes of the circles while maintaining the original values. but this update is reflecting in the data view but not in the web map